# WordPress-Fetch contents/posts of a widget inside dynamic sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom dynamic sidebar displayed on a single post page. I created a custom post type called 'rel_post'. Using ACF I created a block that is displayed when creating/updating a '**rel_post**' post type post. The block has an input where I select what categories are excluded from displaying this post in the sidebar. I created a post called sideBarPost1 and I excluded the category "**books**" (Book is a category of WP default post type **post**) from displaying this post. I created a widget and from the wp-admin, I drag and dropped the posts to that widget.
The problem is I can't access/fetch the posts inside that widget so that I could compare them with the current post category to ignore those posts.

On the sidebar.php file, I tried the following code I only get the widget IDs.

```
$ad_ids=[];
$sidebar_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
if (isset($sidebar_widgets[$sidebar_id])) {
    foreach ($sidebar_widgets[$sidebar_id] as $widget_id) {
        $curr = get_queried_object();
        $ad_ids[]= $curr->ID;
    }
}
```